# Try optimize a specific SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I use this SQL query in PostgreSQL:

```
select *
from (select  row_number()
      over (order by oid1, oid2, oid3)
      as row_number, *
      from snmpProperties)
as toto
where toto.row_number=(select row_number
                       from (select  row_number()
                             over (order by oid1, oid2, oid3)
                             as row_number, *
                             from snmpProperties)
                       as titi
                       where titi.oid1='4'
                             AND titi.oid2='1'
                             AND titi.oid3='')+1;
```

But it uses the same `SELECT` twice:

```
select  row_number()
    over (order by oid1, oid2, oid3)
    as row_number, *
    from snmpProperties
```

Is it possible to factorize my request to use this select one time?

Comment: You _could_ use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). But what exactly are you trying to achieve with that? Maybe it's better if you take a step back and explain what the underlying problem is, you are trying to solve. **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: You could use a CTE to reference a single select multiple times in your statement; but If I get this right, you want to select a row after a specific row in a specific order, and you could directly use the `lag()` [window function for that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

Comment: Yes, this is possible. BTW: I am unable to get the intention of your query.

Comment: I think he wants to get the next row after this row: titi.oid1='4'                              AND titi.oid2='1' AND titi.oid3='' . Sad.

Comment: Hi. thanks for all comments. Yes my original need is to order my table, find a row and get the next row (like a "get next" function). Common Table Expression seems to be the good solution to factorize my query. But thanks to your advices, I found how to rewrite it with lead(), it is better/simple ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      *

from       (select      lag ((oid1,oid2,oid3)) over (order by oid1, oid2, oid3) = ('4','1','')  as is_requested_row
                       ,s.*

            from        snmpProperties as s
            ) as s

where       is_requested_row
;
```

Addition solution, just to demonstrate that it can also be done based on **row_number**

```
select      *

from       (select      min (case when (oid1,oid2,oid3) = ('4','1','') then rn end) over ()   base_rn
                       ,s.*

            from       (select      row_number() over (order by oid1, oid2, oid3) as rn, s.*
                        from        snmpProperties as s
                        ) as s
            ) as s

where       rn = base_rn + 1
;
```

### Explanations

1)
Using the **LAG** window function, every records looks at the (oid1,oid2,oid3) vector of its previous record (when ordered oid1,oid2,oid3) and compares it to ('4','1','').
When the comparison it true that means we are standing on the requested record, the record that follows the record with oid1='4', oid2='1' and oid3=''.

2)
Using the **row_number** window function, we're giving row numbers to the records ordered by oid1,oid2,oid3.
Using the **min** window function, we're putting the row_number of the row with oid1,oid2 and oid3 values of '4','1' and '' in every row in the set.
We're taking the row that its row_number is equal that row_number + 1

Comment: Could you add some explanation of how these queries work? It looks like there's some interesting tips in there, but it's hard to follow what you've done, particularly as the formatting is forcing me to scroll sideways.

Comment: @IMSoP, added. If needed I can clarify later on.

Comment: Hi Dudu, thanks for your answer. I found how to do it with lead(). But your first query with lag() is better, I will use it ! Your second query is a bit hard, but interestfull to understand :)

Comment: @GuillaumeL. P.s. if you liked the answer you might want to upvote